# Jquery scroll to divs with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I did not find any examples that works for me.
What I need to do :

I have a page with a variable number of div, all have `class = "item-elm"`.
I have `2 arrows, up & down`, and when the user click on one of these arrows the body must scroll to get the next div on top etc etc...

But I must allow classic `mouse/touch` scroll also, so the script must `(without fading/showing items)` scroll to next item each time the user click on `'next' or 'prev'` arrow.

I'm a noob jquery user, so what I got working :
- scrolling to absolute top or bottom when clicking on the arrows
- scrolling to the first element

Tried with `serialscroll`, but didn't work, I think I got something wrong when trying to use this

Edit :
I tried : Uikit scrollspy on the item to dynamically add the "active-elm" class `data-uk-scrollspy="{cls: 'active-elm', repeat: true}"` 
Then "onclick" the down arrow, I'm running this :

```
 function nextScroll() { 
    var scrollPos = $('.active-elm').next('.item-elm').scrollTop();
$('body').scrollTo(scrollPos); 
    }
```

Doesn't work :/

Comment: id can not be repeated. Instead you can add class, There should only one id with the one value

Comment: `ID`'s should be unique! I can't see you getting much help on this since you haven't taken the time to research or shown any attempt to try but it's a nice wish list you have.

Comment: "divs with same id" are you using same id in different divs?? first of all the id attribute must be unique, two div can not have same id. use class instead.

Comment: Ok, I tried this to cycle trough jquery, I can remove it and put a class instead, but don't know how to "cycle" through items and getting the next and next position to make it scroll

Comment: @NicolasMeynard give a try for below answer and see if it matches your needs

Answer (score 0):

Add an 'id' attribute to each `<div>`. The value of the id contains the sequence number of the `<div>`, so e.g. `<div id="div1"> ... <div id="div2"> ...` etc.
Enclose the up-arrow in an anchor like `<a href="#divx">...</a>`, where x is one less than the id of the current div and surround the down-arrow in a similar anchor, where x is one more than the id of the current div. For example, the second `<div>` looks like this:

```
<div id="div2">
  <a href="#div1"><img src="up-arrow.png"/></a>
  <a href="#div3"><img src="down-arrow.png"/></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like the easiest and best way, but how can I 'increment' x on each click ?
Because If the user scrolls with his mouse to the second div for example, the  "down arrow" needs to scroll to third
Sorry I'm beginner in JS Jquery
You gave me an idea : using uikit scroll spy and bind a fonction that modify the targets of the arrows dynamically

Comment: So I tried :
Uikit scrollspy on the item to dynamically add the "active-elm" class
data-uk-scrollspy="{cls: 'active-elm', repeat: true}"
Then "onclick" the down arrow, I'm running this :
function nextScroll()
 {
  var scrollPos = $('.active-elm').next('.item-elm').scrollTop();
  $('body').scrollTo(scrollPos);
 }

Doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

Ok then, it works with:

```
function nextScroll()
{
    /*var scrollPos = $('.active-elm').next('[data-uk-scrollspy]').scrollTop;
    $('body').scrollTo(scrollPos);*/
    var next;
      next = $(".active-elm").closest(".item-elm").next();
      $("html, body").scrollTo((next.offset().top) + 65, 300);
}

function prevScroll()
{
    var next;
      next = $(".active-elm").closest(".item-elm").prev().prev();
      $("html, body").scrollTo((next.offset().top) - 65, 300);
}
```

onclick to execute each function when user click on the respective arrows

Then juste use uikit scrollspy to dynamically change "active-elm" class when the element appears

I think it's not the best way to do this, but it actually works ;)

Comment: How come mine isn't scrolling right and left like the example provided? https://jsfiddle.net/k66gLuLk/3/ I am sorting the div at page load. Thanks